# Find all digits $a,b$ such that the number $\overline{aabb}$ is a perfect square

Tags: elementary-number-theory

What is the method for finding numbers $a$ and $b$?

Comment: "Perfect square is divisible by $4$"... so... $9$ isn't a perfect square?

Comment: What does the line above $\overline{aabb}$ mean?

Comment: @5xum, It means that $\overline{aabb}$ is a number with digits $a,b$.

Comment: so, can't you just check all possibilities? There aren't that many...

Comment: @5xum, Well, that would be inefficient in general case.

Comment: @user_99 But your question is not about the general case.  You haven't even described how it generalizes (to other bases? more digits?).  It's your job to define the parameters of the question: as written it is a perfectly reasonable suggestion to check all possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the [divisibility criteria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule) for 11: a number is divisible by 11 if and only if the alternating sum of its digits is divisible by 11.

Hint. Hence the number $\overline{aabb}$ is divisible by $11$ and
$\overline{aabb}=11\cdot \overline{a0b}$.

So if $\overline{aabb}$ is a non-zero perfect square then also $\overline{a0b}$ is divisible by 11, which means that $a=11-b$.

Can you take it from here?

P.S. For the final answer see Erick Wong's comment below.

Comment: Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: @user_99 Any further doubt?

Comment: For $\overline{a0b}$ to be a multiple of $11$ it must be $11$ times $\overline{cb}$ where $c+b = 10$.  If $\overline{aabb}$ is a square, then so is $\overline{cb}$ (since it is the former divided by $11^2$).  The only $2$-digit perfect square whose digits sum to $10$ is $64$.

Comment: @Erick Wong I am sorry but I do not understand what is your final answer. What are $a$ and $b$ then?

Comment: @RobertZ Since $\overline{cb} = 64$, $\overline{a0b} = 11 \cdot 64 = 704$.

Comment: @Erick Wong Perfect, and 7744 is the only positive solution.

Answer (score 1):

Let $N=\overline{aabb}=11(100a+b)$.  For $N$ to be a square, we need $100a+b\equiv a+b\equiv0$ mod $11$.  Since $0\le a,b\le9$, we must have $b=11-a$ (unless $a=b=0$), in which case $N=11(99a+11)=11^2(9a+1)$.  This implies $N/11^2=9a+1\equiv a+1$ mod $8$.  Since the only squares mod $8$ are $0$, $1$, and $4$, we need only consider $a=3$, $7$, and $8$.  Of $9a+1=28$, $64$, and $73$, only $a=7$ corresponds to a square.  Thus $N=7744$ is the only possibility (aside from $0000$).

Answer (score 0):

$$\overline{aabb}=11(100a+b)$$

So, we need $11\mid(100a+b)\iff11\mid(a+b)$

Now $0\le a,b\le9$

Again, $x\equiv0,\pm1,\pm2,\pm3,\pm4,5\pmod{10}$

$\implies x^2\equiv0,1,4,9,6,5$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the possible final two digits modulo $100$ - show you can't have a square ending in $11, 55, 66, 99$ for example, which leaves very few options.

Answer (score 0):

By divisibility of $11$, we have
\begin{align*}
  \overline{aabb} &= 11k \\
   n^2 &= 11k \\
   k &= 11 c^2 \\
  \overline{aabb} &= 11^2c^2 \\
  &= (\overline{cc})^2
\end{align*}

where $1\le a,$ $b$, $c\le 9$

\begin{align*}
  11c \times 11c &= 1100a+11b \\
  11 \times 11 c^2 &= 11(100a+b) \\
  11 c^2 &= 100a+b \\
  &= 99a+a+b \\
  a+b &= 11(c^2-9a) \\
\end{align*}

Note that $2\le a+b \le 18$,
$$
\left\{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    a+b &=& 11 \\
    c^2-9a &=& 1
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Now
\begin{align*}
  9a &= c^2-1 \\
  &= (c+1)(c-1)
\end{align*}

By $c-1<9$ and $3a-3 \ne 2$,
$$
\left \{
  \begin{array}{rcl}
    9 &=& c+1 \\
    a &=& c-1
  \end{array}
\right.$$

Therefore
\begin{align*}
  c &=8 \\
   a &=c-1 \\
   &=7 \\
   b &=11-a \\
   &=4
\end{align*}

> That is $$7744=88^2$$